# How to get current URL from web browser?

Tags: matlab, browser

I'm looking for a way to get the current URL from web browsers such as Chrome, Firefox, or Matlab browser using Matlab code? It it possible to do it?

Comment: Please provide what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the matlab `web` documentation:

```
[stat,h,url] = web() % returns the URL of the current page in the MATLAB Web browser.
```